# Cannot resolve method 'setVisible' in 'String' (Java)

Tags: java, string, javafx

I am writing a code that allows a user to enter a discount code and that code will be applied to the price which will take away 10% subtotal.

What I am trying to do is to not have the discount code and the amount appear on the GUI unless a discount code has been applied (there is a window that will pop up and once they finish the can close and the information is there).

What has worked so far is the discount amount has worked. So it is not apparent when opening the program and when the discount code matches and is applied then the reduction amount is there.

However here is where I am getting trouble. I am trying to do the same thing with the discount code. So for example if you enter "SALE10" as the code then the GUI will display the code that has been entered and valid as well as the amount that has been taken off the subtotal.

I am trying to do that by using the setVisible booleans and visiblility tags on the FXML.

```
discountCode.setVisible(true);
discountAmount.setVisible(true);
```

I have those within the function but `discountCode.setVisible(true);` has a red line underneath and the error thats given is Cannot resolve method 'setVisible' in 'String' which I am unsure on what that means. I am more confused on the fact that the discountAmount works but discountCode doesn't

Here is the full function of it

```
public void applyDiscount(String discountCode){
    if("SALE10".equals(discountCode)){
        BigDecimal preDiscount = new BigDecimal(subtotalSum.getText().substring(1));
        BigDecimal discountAmountValue = preDiscount.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.10"));
        BigDecimal newSubtotal = preDiscount.subtract(discountAmountValue);
        subtotalSum.setText("$" + newSubtotal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        BigDecimal taxRate = new BigDecimal("0.12");
        BigDecimal newTotalPrice = newSubtotal.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.add(taxRate));
        totalPrice.setText("$" + newTotalPrice.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        discountAmount.setText("-$" + discountAmountValue.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        discountCode.setVisible(true);
        discountAmount.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        discountCode.setVisible(false);
        discountAmount.setVisible(false);
        //will keep the text hidden if code is invalid
    }
}
```

And here is the section of the FXML that has those Text

```xml
<Text fx:id="discountCode" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="223.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="-$9.99" wrappingWidth="58.5" visible="false"/>
<Text fx:id="discountAmount" layoutX="110.0" layoutY="223.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="-$9.99" wrappingWidth="58.5" visible="false"/>
```

Comment: why do you assume the String class has a setVisible method? String is not a UI component

Comment: Check the type for `discountAmount`. Is it a `String`?

Comment: @Stultuske I have it so when you press a button on the UI it will prompt up a screen which will have a textfield for the user to enter a code. So this one will apply the discount if the discount code is valid

Comment: @Cyrus that doesn't answer the question. UI components having a setVisible method is logical, for a String it makes no sense.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca its a string

Comment: @Cyrus chances are it's not, if it doesn't show an error. Double check.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca discountCode is a String. I doubt discountAmount to be one

Comment: @Stultuske that's my point.

Comment: Side note:  Instead of doing multiplication and rounding yourself, just use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`.  For example, `NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); subtotalSum.setText(fmt.format(newSubtotal));`

Comment: The quick fix to your code is changing `applyDiscount(String discountCode)` to `applyDiscount(Text discountCode)` and changing `if("SALE10".equals(discountCode)){` to `if("SALE10".equals(discountCode.getText())){`. That's assuming you are trying to pass the `Text` `FXML` node to the method. `FXML` nodes scope should cover the whole class, so does the node need to be passed to the class in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

Your class has probably fields `discountAmount` and `discountCode`.

In your method you have a parameter that is also named `discountCode` and that parameter shadows the field (i.e. you can no longer access the field only be the name `discountCode`).

You could either rename the parameter or access the field by prepending its name with `this.`:

```
public void applyDiscount(String discountCode){
    if("SALE10".equals(discountCode)){
        BigDecimal preDiscount = new BigDecimal(subtotalSum.getText().substring(1));
        BigDecimal discountAmountValue = preDiscount.multiply(new BigDecimal("0.10"));
        BigDecimal newSubtotal = preDiscount.subtract(discountAmountValue);
        subtotalSum.setText("$" + newSubtotal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        BigDecimal taxRate = new BigDecimal("0.12");
        BigDecimal newTotalPrice = newSubtotal.multiply(BigDecimal.ONE.add(taxRate));
        totalPrice.setText("$" + newTotalPrice.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        discountAmount.setText("-$" + discountAmountValue.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

        this.discountCode.setVisible(true); // change here
        discountAmount.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        this.discountCode.setVisible(false); // change here
        discountAmount.setVisible(false);
        //will keep the text hidden if code is invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an assumption. Since the OP made it clear that he's aware discountCode is a String, it's not sure there's a field discountCode of a different type

Comment: @Stultuske Given the FXML included, I think it is more than just an assumption.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I agree there should be one, when looking at that, but seeing as the OP is wondering why there is no setVisible for class String, I'm not convinced the OP is not capable of making errors against that

Answer (score 1):

Here is an app that can hopefully help you. I would use a `Map` to keep up with valid discounts or a `List` if your valid discounts are POJOs. From there, I would use a `Set` to keep up with the valid discounts that were entered. You could use a `ListView`, `VBox`, or `HBox` to show which valid discounts were entered.

### Valid Codes

- BIGSAVINGS
- LUCKYDAY
- LILSOMETHING

### Main

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Map<String, Double> validDiscountCodes = new HashMap();
        validDiscountCodes.put("BIGSAVINGS", .50);
        validDiscountCodes.put("LUCKYDAY", .75);
        validDiscountCodes.put("LILSOMETHING", .10);
       
        Set<String> verifiedDiscountCodes = new HashSet();
        
        Label lblDiscountCode = new Label("Discount Code: ");
        TextField tfDiscountCode = new TextField();    
        Button btnDiscountCode = new Button("Enter");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(lblDiscountCode, tfDiscountCode, btnDiscountCode);
        HBox hbDisplayEnteredValidCodes = new HBox();
        hbDisplayEnteredValidCodes.setSpacing(5);
        btnDiscountCode.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
            if(validDiscountCodes.containsKey(tfDiscountCode.getText().toUpperCase()))
            {
                if(verifiedDiscountCodes.add(tfDiscountCode.getText().toUpperCase()))
                {
                    hbDisplayEnteredValidCodes.getChildren().add(new Label(tfDiscountCode.getText().toUpperCase()));

                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Discount Code");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Valid Code");
                    alert.setContentText(tfDiscountCode.getText() + " is a Valid Code");
                    alert.show();
                    PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
                    delay.setOnFinished(e -> alert.close());
                    delay.play();
                    tfDiscountCode.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Discount Code");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Code Already Applied");
                    alert.setContentText(tfDiscountCode.getText() + " has already been applied!");
                    alert.show();
                    PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
                    delay.setOnFinished(e -> alert.close());
                    delay.play();
                    tfDiscountCode.setText("");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Discount Code");
                alert.setHeaderText("Invalid Code");
                alert.setContentText(tfDiscountCode.getText() + " is not a Valid Code!");
                alert.show();
                PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
                delay.setOnFinished(e -> alert.close());
                delay.play();
            }
        });
        
        TextArea taDiscountApplied = new TextArea();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("Discount Codes Applied:").append(System.lineSeparator());
        Button btnCheckOut = new Button("Checkout");
        btnCheckOut.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> 
        {
            for(String verifiedDiscountCode : verifiedDiscountCodes)
            {
                stringBuilder.append("\t").append(verifiedDiscountCode).append(": ").append(validDiscountCodes.get(verifiedDiscountCode) * 100).append(" off!").append(System.lineSeparator());
            }   
            
            taDiscountApplied.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            btnCheckOut.setDisable(true);
            btnDiscountCode.setDisable(true);
        });
        
  
        VBox root = new VBox(hBox, hbDisplayEnteredValidCodes, btnCheckOut, taDiscountApplied);
        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(root), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

[image]